# Kappa2 zero value despite almost identical ratings

Tags: r, cohens-kappa

I have a dataset with self and informant ratings of a pathological outcome in 47 people. Despite the fact that the self and informant ratings are almost identical, kappa2 (irr) gives me a kappa value of 0 (meaning chance performance) with NaN z and p-values. I have removed missing values from the data

I used the following code:

> library(irr)
>   kappa2(df, weight = "squared")

The results are as follows:

```
Cohen's Kappa for 2 Raters (Weights: squared)

 Subjects = 46 
   Raters = 2 
    Kappa = 0 

   z = NaN 
  p-value = NaN
```

The data is literally all 'normal' values from one rater, and all but two 'normal' values from the other rater, ie extremely high concordance at face value.

Why am I getting kappa=0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With highly skewed classes, kappa will estimate chance agreement ($p_c$) as very high. This, in turn, will result in a very low value of $\kappa$ despite a high degree of observed agreement ($p_o$):

$$
\kappa = \frac{p_o - p_c}{1 - p_c}
$$

This property has been dubbed one of the "paradoxes" of the kappa coefficient. To understand why this is, you need to dig into how kappa estimates chance agreement. Basically, with high skew, one of the following two products will be very high and the other will be very low.

$$
p_c = \Bigg(\frac{f_1}{n}\Bigg)\Bigg(\frac{g_1}{n}\Bigg) + \Bigg(\frac{f_2}{n}\Bigg)\Bigg(\frac{g_2}{n}\Bigg)
$$

Here is a contingency table for two raters (i.e., $A$ and $B$) assigning items to two mutually exclusive response categories (i.e., $1$ or $2$). The marginal totals are sums; for example, $f_1=a+c$.

$$
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
~&A=1&A=2&\text{Total}\\ \hline
B=1&a&b&g_1\\ \hline
B=2&c&d&g_2\\ \hline
\text{Total}&f_1&f_2&n\\ \hline
\end{array}
$$

**References**

Feinstein, A. R., & Cicchetti, D. V. (1990). High agreement but low kappa: I. The problems of two paradoxes. *Journal of Clinical Epidemiology, 43*(6), 543–549.

Comment: Thank you Jeffrey for a clear and referenced answer, that makes a lot of sense.